# FromSqlRaw returns 0 elements from SELECT + CONTAINSTABLE with two parameters

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a SELECT with a CONTAINSTABLE in SQL SERVER passing two parameters. One is a DataTable and the another one is a string.

Follow the code:

```
         DataTable table = Produto.CreateDataTable(produtos);

         SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@produto",
            Value = table,
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured,
            TypeName = "dbo.produto" // Criar no SM_v1.
        };

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@produto_marca",
            Value = produtoMarca
        };

        var nomesProdutoRanking = await _v1Context.NomesProdutoRanking.FromSqlRaw("SELECT TOP(40) p.id_produto AS IdProduto, p.nome AS Nome, fts.[rank] AS Rank " +
            "FROM {0} AS p INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(produto, pesquisa, {1}, language N'BRAZILIAN') AS fts ON p.id_produto = fts.[key] " +
            "WHERE ISNULL(fts.rank, 0) > 0 ORDER BY 3", param, param2).ToListAsync();
```

produtoMarca:

```
( "*BACON*" near "*SALGADO*" near "*ENROLADO*" )
```

The Model:

```
public class NomeProdutoRanking
{
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<NomeProdutoRanking>(e =>
        {
            e.HasNoKey();
        });
    }
```

CreateDataTable:

```
    public static DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<Produto> produtos)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("id_produto", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("nome", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("peso_variavel", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("ean", typeof(bool));

        DataRow workRow;

        foreach (Produto produto in produtos)
        {
            workRow = table.NewRow();
            workRow[0] = produto.IdProduto;
            workRow[1] = produto.Nome;
            workRow[2] = produto.PesoVariavel;
            workRow[3] = produto.Ean;
            table.Rows.Add(workRow);
        }
        
        return table;
    }
```

I also created a Type dbo.produto in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[produto] AS TABLE(
    [id_produto] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [peso_variavel] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ean] [bit] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id_produto] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

The return FromSqlRaw is 0 elements.

A don´t know if it´s possible to create a select like this one, any ideas?

Comment: How to apply this string.format?

Comment: The real table is called "table" as variable. And it is definied as Structured. I read something about it.

Comment: I added the Type created in SQL Server, still not working.

Comment: @Selvin It's a table valued parameter, so the table name itself is not being parameterized, it's the whole table being passed in

Comment: Have you executed this in SSMS and it returns a result?

Comment: Sorry, guys! It wasn´t working well in SSMS. I fixed and now this code is passing well. The problem was in the DATA in SSMS.

Comment: So you don't have a question anymore? Perhaps you should just delete it. Side note: use a verbatim string for your SQL `@"select ..."` that way you can put newlines directly into it and make it more readable